# How to pass all arguments to self and remove args?

Tags: python

Apologies if the title did not make any sense because I don't know how else to phrase it. I would like to know if there is a way to pass all my arguments `args` into `self` and be able to call the arguments in self without typing `self.args.`

For example, in the following I pass `args` to `self.args` but I'll need to type `self.args.units` if I want to access the variable units.

```
class model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super(model, self).__init__()
                
        self.args = args            
        print(self.args.units)
```

Is there a way for me to call `self.units` without having to pass `args.units` to `self.units`?

```
print(self.units)
```

`args` are the arguments I pass in when calling the program.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--player_attention_type', type=str)
parser.add_argument('--player_velocity_encoder_units', nargs="*", type=int)
args = parser.parse_args()
```

Comment: What is `args`? A `list`, a `dict`, or an instance of some class with an attribute `units`? You might try `self.__dict__.update(args)` (if it is a dict) or `self.__dict__.update(args.__dict__)` (for an object), but there's probably a better way...

Comment: @tobias_k updated my post. args are the arguments i pass in when calling the program. So its just an object

Comment: You don't pass anything *to* `self`; `self` itself is an argument. I would just be explicit: `self.unit = args.unit`, etc. You only have to write `__init__` once.

Comment: thank you, I agree that I only pass to init once but the number of arguments itself can get really really large so I was just wondering if there is a way to pass them all in and then call them later on without having to type self.args.units etc

Comment: My humble opinion is that if you don't explicitly assign the attributes (which you anyway, only have to do it once) you will not understand your own code in a month from now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work for an `argparse` result:

```
class model(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, args):
        super(model, self).__init__()

        for key, value in args.__dict__.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
        print(self.units)
```

[`__dict__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#object.__dict__) is a special property that most objects have. It's the objects attributes (dot properties) expressed as a `dict`.